# Send a chat message into MS Teams as MS Teams app with access token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to send a chat message into MS Teams 1:1 chat as a registered app?

For example:
Every one hour a cron is triggered and sends a MS Graph request (with an access token) to send a chat message into a chat with a specific id.

Comment: Are you looking for the same?In that sample it shows how to get started with authentication in a bot for Microsoft Teams.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso/csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: YES, it's possible.

You need to get access to MS graph on behalf of a user, because an App on it's own cannot send chat messages.

Follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Summary of steps:

1. Register an App
2. Give the App Api permissions
3. Consent with permissions by your organisation
4. Get user authorization_code (modify and paste this into your browser: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={application_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7193/api/test/authRedirect&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20chat.read%20chat.ReadWrite&state=12345](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7Bapplication_id%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7193/api/test/authRedirect&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20chat.read%20chat.ReadWrite&state=12345)
5. copy a "code" from previous response
6. Call POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) with parameters from tutorial mentioned above
7. Tadaaa!! You have your access token for calling the MS Graph API

I ran into an issue with scopes. In the tutorial a scope "mail.read" is requested as well. But I was unable to obtain a token with this scope. So for testing purposes I leave only "user.read" scope and after it worked I experimented with additional scopes.

When you change the scope, you need to repeat the step 4. to get a new authorization_code